# AngularJS - wait for data from server and add them correctly to list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-apply

I am currently working on an AngularJS project in which I have to get project  information, for a specific month and year, from the server and show them to the user.

First of all I'm getting a list of Project Id's (projectList), which can be variable, and then I need to get the info on those projects for a specific year and month. With this code I'm trying to get the data and to refresh the data when the last projects is successful. After the data is fetched, I use a ng-repeat to show it to the user.

```
$scope.getData = function(){
        $scope.projectInfoList = [];


        for(var index=0; index < $scope.projectList.length; index++){


            projectService.getProject($scope.model.year, $scope.model.month, parseInt($scope.projectList[index]) ).success(function(data){

                var listInput = { projectID : $scope.projectList[index], data :  data};

                $scope.projectInfoList.push(listInput); 

                if(index == $scope.projectList.length - 1){
                    $scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        };
    }
```

This has 2 mistakes.

1. It adds only data to the last index.
2. It doesn't refresh the data immediately when I request data for another month or year

I have looked for solutions with [$q.all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248095/q-all-not-working-for-multiple-promises) but I'm not sure how I would use it together with variable amount of functions of 'projectService.getProject(..)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anonymous callback that you give to the function `success` use a closure to the variable `index`.

But, your anonymous callback will be called **asynchronously** (when the call will be done). So when it will be called when `index` will be the last index of the array (so here `$scope.projectList.length - 1`).

To avoid that, you can use the following pattern:

```
for(var index=0; index < $scope.projectList.length; index++){
    (function (index) {
        projectService.getProject($scope.model.year, $scope.model.month, parseInt($scope.projectList[index]) ).success(function(data){

            var listInput = { projectID : $scope.projectList[index], data :  data};

            $scope.projectInfoList.push(listInput); 

            if(index == $scope.projectList.length - 1){
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        });
    })(index)
}
```

Your second mistake is probably because you change the reference of the array `projectInfoList` in your function with `$scope.projectInfoList = [];`.

Take a look at this post for more details on this last problem: [ng-repeat not updating on update of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29849293/ng-repeat-not-updating-on-update-of-array/29849368#29849368)

Comment: Alright! Works like a charm! Thanks for the link to the ng-repeat not updating. I didn't find that.